# Google Analytics Visitors drop-off for certain region of site only

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have an issue with the tracking on my site where I have seen a dramatic drop off of visitors to the site from a certain region. I have four regions on my site at the moment, these are UK, EU, US and RoW (Rest of the World). The UK, EU and US regions are unaffected, only the RoW region suffers this drop-off. I have included a screen shot below from my GA account, which shows this effect.

My GA code, which is included on **every** page on the site is below. I have changed the UA account number intentionally for this example. There have been no changes made to the GA account or the tracking code in a live environment for some considerable time, but for some reason I am seeing the drop-off for this region only.

In the code below I am not tracking page views on certain pages as I have event tracking setup for these pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18721873-5']);

    _gaq.push(['_setCookiePath', '/row/']);


    if ( typeof(p_page) != 'undefined') {

        // do nothing if user is on above pages

        // N.B. there are a series of conditions in this if statement checking that we are not on a particular page
    } else {

        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    }

</script>
```

[image: Visitors Overview]

Comment: The first thing i would do is to remove the `if ( typeof(p_page) != 'undefined')` during one day to be sure that's not coming from an error in your conditions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was unfortunately caused by a non GA-related issue and was solely down to a Geolocation lookup performing incorrectly. I was still receiving the same traffic, however they were being re-directed to a different GA account.

Answer (score 1):

Visits is to broad to look at. You should go through each traffic source one by one to see if any specific source has caused the drop, i've seen similar drops from referral traffic Google / Referrer to be exact. It was caused by a huge drop in traffic coming from image searches all the while organics were still on the rise.